# Always getting primary monitor DPI

Tags: c#, .net, dpi, multiple-monitors

I need to get dpi of an external monitor, but I always get dpi of the primary monitor. I also have done manifest settings.
I used following code to fetch it.

**Definition**

```
public static void GetPerMonitorDPIEx(ref double dx, ref double dy, int x, 
      int y)
    {
        UInt32 dpiX = 0;
        UInt32 dpiY = 0;
        System.Drawing.Point pt = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
        bool m = SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext((int)PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS.DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);
        var mhandle = MonitorFromPoint( pt, Utils.DEFAULT_TO_NEAREST);
        uint m5 = GetDpiForMonitor(mhandle, MONITOR_DPI_TYPE.MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI, out dpiX, out dpiY);
        dx = (double)dpiX / 96;
        dy = (double)dpiY / 96;
    }
```

**Call**

```
GetPerMonitorDPIEx(ref dpiX, ref dpiY, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Left + 1, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[i].Bounds.Top +1);
```

I could see the monitor handle is coming correct for both the display, after that dpi values always coming from the primary display.

Comment: Please show your loop through screens.

Comment: foreach(var i in Screen.AllScreens)

Comment: If that is your loop, `AllScreens[i]` won't work/compile, cause index of `AllScreens` is `int`.

Comment: Actually, I checked the value of left and top for each monitor, they are coming proper.

Comment: yeah I did casting it to int.

Comment: You can't cast type `Screen` to `int`. Check the value of your `i` in both of iterations, it should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

While researching the same topic, I stumbled across your question:
According to Microsoft Docs:

> `GetDpiForMonitor` is not DPI aware and should not be used if the
> calling thread is per-monitor DPI aware. For the DPI-aware version of
> this API, see `GetDpiForWindow`.

source: [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getdpiformonitor#remarks)

Answer (score 1):

First set your application as dpi aware then try to chek the output of

uint m5 = GetDpiForMonitor(mhandle, MONITOR_DPI_TYPE.MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI, out dpiX, out dpiY);